# How to loop through an array whose length includes a decimal value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I require assistance with array looping in React/JavaScript. Essentially, I'm working on an LMS application that will display the Star ratings. I'll actually pull the average ratings from the database, populate this value in an array, and loop through a star svg to display the number of stars.

Assume the average rating is 4, then my code is correct. It will display four filled stars and one empty star.

However, if the average rating is 3.5 (includes decimal value), my code fails and generates an error.

Any ideas on how to handle the Arrays in this situation? Below is my code snippet as well as the error in the second scenario.

```js
          const average_rating =data.aggregate.avg.rating;

          <Flex alignItems="center" justify="start">

              {Array.from(Array(average_rating).keys()).map((id) => {
                return <Star key={id} fillColor="#EACA4E" />;
              })}

              {Array.from(Array(5 - average_rating).keys()).map((id) => {
                return <Star key={id} fillColor="#e2e8f0" />;
              })}

            </Flex>
```

Error

[image]

Comment: I'd probably use a `Math.ceil(average_rating)` to round the rating up to the nearest full digit. Then, on your last star, calculate the decimal value difference to know how far you need to fill that star.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because `Array` takes only integer value. Actually instead of multiple maps, you can simplify with on iteration and find out the stars state (full/half/empty).

```js
const stars = (avg) =>
  Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => {
    if (avg >= i + 1) {
      return "full";
    } else if (avg > i) {
      return "half";
    }
    return "empty";
  });
  

console.log(stars(2));
console.log(stars(3.5));
console.log(stars(5));
```